# Percentile_CONT function returns multiple rows

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I am writing Percentile_CONT function which returns multiple rows as a result. I was assuming that PERCENTILE_CONT function should return only one value.This is my SQL

```
select PERCENTILE_CONT(0.5) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY RegoToSrvc  DESC) 
           OVER (PARTITION BY Hospid) as MedianSeconds,
       'MedianWaitTime' as Flag
from A   
where A.RegistrationDate  between '20140701' and '20140731' and
      Hospid = 21
```

Comment: Which database system? It looks like Oracle or SQL Server 2012 or later.

Comment: If PERCENTILE_CONT returns multiple rows, it has to be part of the FROM clause.

Comment: Are you getting one row per `Hospid` or more than one row?

Comment: It is SQL server 2012, I am getting multiple rows but don't know why?

Answer (score 2):

You are using a window function, so there is no reduction in the number of rows in the set.  If you want the median, just take one row:

```
select TOP 1 PERCENTILE_CONT(0.5) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY RegoToSrvc  DESC) 
           OVER (PARTITION BY Hospid) as MedianSeconds,
       'MedianWaitTime' as Flag
from A   
where A.RegistrationDate  between '20140701' and '20140731' and
      Hospid = 21;
```

Comment: Thanks, I just now found out that distinct will also work, but I got the point that it should just pick up one value out of the all rows.

Comment: `distinct` will work, but because you are limiting the query to only one `HospId`, `distinct` will generate additional work.  `top 1` should be more efficient.